# Trying to sort out multiple submit buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I sort out multiple submit buttons, I am trying to run a javascript call "pull()" when user submit play button and i want to run php call "score.php" when user submit save button.

```
<form id="slotbox" name="slotbox" onsubmit="pull(); return false;">
<input class="Playbutton" id="PlayButton" type="submit" name="play" value="Play" />

<form action="score.php" method="POST">
<p>score<input name="money" type="text" /></p>
<input id="save" name="save" type="button" value="save"/>
</form>
</form>
```

What do i need to add/modify the code to make it work.Any advice will be grateful.

Comment: I don't think you can have forms nested inside each other.

Comment: A form within a form is not valid. Use a javascript onsubmit handler and check for the id of the clicked button, then do whatever.

Comment: In addition to the invalid form nesting, there is only *one* submit button posted. When a form request is made by a *real submit button* (i.e. type=submit) it will be sent to the server as form data (e.g. play=Play) just like another input value.

Comment: i will try onsubmit handler but i dont know i never done this so, im not very confident with it

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple `submit` buttons, you can use the `formaction` attribute of the buttons to override the form's `action` tag:

```
<form id="slotbox" name="slotbox" >
<input class="Playbutton" id="PlayButton" type="submit" onclick="pull(); return false;" name="play" value="Play" />
<p>score<input name="money" type="text" /></p>
<input id="save" name="save" type="submit" formaction="score.php" value="save"/>
</form>
```

I've also removed the `onsubmit` attribute of the form, and moved its code to the `onclick` attribute of the `Play` button, because the `onsubmit` code runs before submitting to the `action` or `formaction` URLs.

Comment: no it didnt work when i click save it only run javascript and it doesn't run score.php

Comment: two new error one is when i click play button nothing happens, and save fuction works but the database is showing null that means score hasnt being posted to score.php. I think i will use onsubmit handler, the only trouble is i don't know how it works but thanks for your advice.

Comment: Maybe there's something in the PHP that isn't working with this HTML, but I'm not sure what it would be.